# CodeIgniter - return only one row?

Tags: database, codeigniter

At the moment if I am doing a query on the database that should only return one row, using:

```
...query stuff...
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->result();
return $ret[0]->campaign_id;
```

Is there a CodeIgniter function to return the first row?
something like `$query->row();`

Or even better would be the ability to, if there was only one row,
to just use the query object directly.

e.g. `$query->campaign_id;`

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You've just answered your own question :)
You can do something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->row();
return $ret->campaign_id;
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: `$row = json_decode($query->row(), true);` ended up using-->  `$row = $query->result_array()[0];`

Answer (score 33):

This is better way as it gives you result in a single line:

```
$this->db->query("Your query")->row()->campaign_id;
```

Comment: How can we use this like ternary operator? `(query)?(getresult) : (null)`

Answer (score 14):

To add on to what Alisson said you could check to see if a row is returned.

```
// Query stuff ...
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $row = $query->row(); 
    return $row->campaign_id;
}

return null; // or whatever value you want to return for no rows found
```

Answer (score 10):

To make the code clear that you are intending to get the first row, CodeIgniter now allows you to use:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->first_row();
}
```

To retrieve the first row.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->get()->row()->campaign_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

**If you require to get only one record from database table using codeigniter query then you can do it using row(). we can easily return one row from database in codeigniter.**

```
$data = $this->db->get("items")->row();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change only in two line and you are getting actually what you want.

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$ret = $query->row();
return $ret->campaign_id;
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

We can get a single using limit in query

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$q  = $this->db->get()->row();

return $q->campaign_id;
```

Documentation :
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Good first answer, but please take a look at the [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for proper code editing :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
$limit = 1
$offset = 0

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('items', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

Option 2

```
$this->db->get("items")->row();
```

Comment: I don't know why it got a minus score. But I just realized something crazy. Option 1 (limit) is faster than Option 2 (row). Since Option 2 will retrieve all results and get the first row.

Answer (score -3):

class receipt_model extends CI_Model {

```
   public function index(){

      $this->db->select('*');

      $this->db->from('donor_details');

      $this->db->order_by('donor_id','desc');

      $query=$this->db->get();

      $row=$query->row();

      return $row;
 }
```

}