# Codeigniter $this->db->get(), how do I return values for a specific row?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Say I have a database table with three columns: ID, Name, and Age.
I need to find the user with a specific (unique) ID, and then return the age. Currently, I am using the following code

```
$this->db->where('id', '3');
$q = $this->db->get('my_users_table');
```

How do I go about getting the age for this user? I think I have to use

```
$q->result()
```

But not sure how to use it with one row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - return only one row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280235/codeigniter-return-only-one-row)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**SOLUTION ONE**

```
$this->db->where('id', '3');
// here we select every column of the table
$q = $this->db->get('my_users_table');
$data = $q->result_array();

echo($data[0]['age']);
```

**SOLUTION TWO**

```
// here we select just the age column
$this->db->select('age');
$this->db->where('id', '3');
$q = $this->db->get('my_users_table');
$data = $q->result_array();

echo($data[0]['age']);
```

**SOLUTION THREE**

```
$this->db->select('age');
$this->db->where('id', '3');
$q = $this->db->get('my_users_table');
// if id is unique, we want to return just one row
$data = array_shift($q->result_array());

echo($data['age']);
```

**SOLUTION FOUR (NO ACTIVE RECORD)**

```
$q = $this->db->query('SELECT age FROM my_users_table WHERE id = ?',array(3));
$data = array_shift($q->result_array());
echo($data['age']);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
Is there a more efficient way to do this though?

Comment: perhaps for such an simple query plain SQL would be more straigh forward choice, anyway i think i doesn't change a lot between these 4 cases

Answer (score 6):

you can use row() instead of result().

```
$this->db->where('id', '3');
$q = $this->db->get('my_users_table')->row();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Accessing a single row**

```
//Result as an Object
$result = $this->db->select('age')->from('my_users_table')->where('id', '3')->limit(1)->get()->row();
echo $result->age;

//Result as an Array
$result = $this->db->select('age')->from('my_users_table')->where('id', '3')->limit(1)->get()->row_array();
echo $result['age'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are dynamically getting your data e.g When you need data based on the user logged in by their id use consider the following code example for a No Active Record:

```
 $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM my_users_table WHERE id = ?', $this->session->userdata('id'));

 return $query->row_array();
```

This will return a specific row based on your the set session data of user.

Answer (score -1):

You simply use this in one row.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable',array('id'=>'3'));
```