# Getting the value of a row in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the value of a row in the database but not working out that well. I not sure if can work like this.

I am just trying to get the value but also make sure it from the group config and the key.

**Model**

```
function getTitle() {
  return $this->db->get('setting', array(
    ->where('group' => 'config'),
    ->where('key' => 'config_meta_title'),
    ->where('value'=> ) // Want to be able to return any thing in the value
  ))->row();
}
```

In the controller I would do this:

```
function index() {
  $data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();
  $this->load->view('sample', $data);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter $this->db->get(), how do I return values for a specific row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541291/codeigniter-this-db-get-how-do-i-return-values-for-a-specific-row)

Comment: I only need to get the value how do I do so but still have group and key

Comment: In your second code block you mistyped function -> funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have this line set to this:

```
$data['title'] $this->document->getTitle();
```

That should be an `=` assignment for `$this->document->getTitle();` like this:

```
$data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();
```

But then in your function you should actually return the `setting` value from your query with `row()->setting`:

```
function getTitle() {
  return $this->db->get('setting', array(
    ->where('group' => 'config'),
    ->where('key' => 'config_meta_title'),
    ->where('value'=> ) // Should return this row information but can not.
  ))->row()->setting;
}
```

But that said, I am unclear about this:

```
->where('value'=> ) // Should return this row information but can not.
```

A `WHERE` condition is not a `SELECT`. It is a condition connected to a `SELECT` that allows you to `SELECT` certain values `WHERE` a criteria is met. So that should be set to something, but not really sure what since your code doesn’t provide much details.

Comment: what do I put where the value is to be able to get what's in that only

Comment: if I do this ->select('value') and remove this "=>" should that return what's in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution Working Now. For Getting Single Item From Database In Codeigniter

**Loading In Library**

```
function getTitle($value) {
   $this->CI->db->select($value);
   $this->CI->db->where("group","config");
   $this->CI->db->where("key","config_meta_title");
   $query = $this->CI->db->get('setting');
   return $query->row()->$value;
}
```

**Or Loading In Model**

```
function getTitle($value) {
   $this->db->select($value);
   $this->db->where("group","config");
   $this->db->where("key","config_meta_title");
   $query = $this->db->get('setting');
   return $query->row()->$value;
}
```