# get_select_option function with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am newbie to php I need help 
I want to add where clause to this 'get_select_option'

my get_select_option code is here

```html
function get_select_option($table,$id,$name,$selected=0){
  $query = $this->db->get($table);
  $select = '<option value="">SELECT</option>';
  if($query->num_rows()>0){
   foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
   $selected_option = ($selected==$row[$id]) ? ' selected="selected" ':' ';
    $select.='<option value="'.$row[$id].'" '. $selected_option.'>'.trim(strtoupper($row[$name])).'</option>';
   }
  }
  return $select;
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8541303/689579?

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter you can set the `where` clause by using `$this->db->where();`. The code will be -

```
$this->db->where('fieldname', 'valuetomatch');
$query = $this->db->get($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line   `$this->db->where('column_name','your_value');` in the below function above your `$query = $this->db->get($table);` statement

```
function get_select_option($table,$id,$name,$selected=0){
            $this->db->where('column_name','your_value');
            $query = $this->db->get($table);
            $select = '<option value="">SELECT</option>';
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
                foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
                $selected_option = ($selected==$row[$id]) ? ' selected="selected" ':' ';
                    $select.='<option value="'.$row[$id].'" '. $selected_option.'>'.trim(strtoupper($row[$name])).'</option>';
                }
            }
            return $select;
        }
```

Comment: welcome...dont forget to accept if this solved your problem :)