# Accessing array of data inside the controller from the model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to use the `$data['main']` and get a specific row or data from it which is: `extra_id`

I would use `extra_id` for another function.

I tried accessing the data from the `$data['main']` just like what I did on the view of the other page which is: `$extra_id = $main->result()->extra_id;`

Unfortunately, it did not work.

controller:

```
public function viewData($id)
    {   

    $this->load->model('myModel');

    $data['main'] = $this->MyModel->getMainData($id);

    $extra_id = $main->result()->extra_id; //error here. undefined variable main.

    $data['extra'] = $this->MyModel->getExtraData($extra_id);



    $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

model:

```
public function getMainData($id) {
        $this->db->select('main.id as extra_id');
        $this->db->select('main.*');
        $this->db->select('extra.*');

        $this->db->from('main');

        $this->db->join('extra', 'extra.main_id = main.id');

        $query = $this->db->get();  
        return $query;
}
```

Comment: Better do `$data['main']->result()->extra_id;`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Ok. I tried it. It produced another error which is `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: If you have more than one result, the error is correct. `var_dump()` and look what you get.

Comment: Also read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541291/codeigniter-this-db-get-how-do-i-return-values-for-a-specific-row  and use `result_array()` like shown in the examples

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I only have one column result

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I have edited the question and added the model

Comment: May read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506789/codeigniter-result-vs-result-array too

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I have used `result_array()`. It still doesnt work. Displays the same error.

Comment: Do `var_dump($data['main']->result())` and `var_dump($data['main']->result_array())`to see what you get.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I just did it. It returned a result. One row.

Comment: And how does is look like, is it an array of objects is it only object?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `$extra_id = $data['main']->extra_id;` and `$query = $this->db->get()->row();` worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please learn how to access $variables of any kind `arrays,objects,...`. It seesm everthing is fine, but you dont now how to access something that you can see. But that is basic of PHP syntax that you have to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this...

In codeiginter the `result()` extract more than one rows on object form and function `row()` is used to obtain only first row in object form.

Controller:

```
public function viewData($id)
    {   

    $this->load->model('myModel');

    $data['main'] = $this->MyModel->getMainData($id);

    $extra_id = $data['main']->extra_id; //error here. undefined variable main.

    $data['extra'] = $this->MyModel->getExtraData($extra_id);


    $this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function getMainData($id) {
        $this->db->select('main.id as extra_id');
        $this->db->select('main.*');
        $this->db->select('extra.*');

        $this->db->from('main');

        $this->db->join('extra', 'extra.main_id = main.id');

        $query = $this->db->get()->row();  
        return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `$data['main']` and then use `$main`....it doesn't work that way. Try this:

```
$extra_id = $data['main']->result()->extra_id;
```

My guess is the place you copied that bit of code from, you assigned it to a variable called `$main` in that method.

Comment: Ok. I tried it. It produced another error which is `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Then your `$this->MyModel->getMainData($id);` isn't returning it correctly. Use `var_dump()` to debug and figure out what you are actually outputting.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the model part.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
$extra_id = $data['main']->result()[0]->extra_id;
```

And Use $id in where clause in model.

```
 $this->db->where("id",$id);
```