# Codeigniter accessing array values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I simply want to know how to access array elements retrieved from a database. I have the following code to get the names of each item in my database.

```
$plat_options = $this->db->get('tblplatform_options')->select('name')->result();
```

How do I go about accessing the name from the array `$plat_options`? Typically I would do `$plat_options[0]` for the first element in C#, how is this done in `php/codeigniter`?

Comment: Start by doing a `print_r($plat_options);` that will show you the array in a pretty readable and understandable format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP/Codeigniter, can be done in the same way:

```
$plat_options[0] //if you have this element, usually is better to check if exists.
```

You can retrieve all the elements with `foreach($plat_options as $option){...}`
You can cast to object: https://www.kathirvel.com/php-convert-or-cast-array-to-object-object-to-array/

Or use a Codeigniter Helper (assuming you are using CI3): http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/array_helper.html

I recomend to know which is your array format and retrieve that way (if you don't know, you can do a: `var_dump($plat_options)` ) to know if is an associative array.

You can use the result_array() function:

```
$data = $plat_options->result_array();
echo($data[0]['name']);
```

or:

```
$data = array_shift($q->result_array());
echo($data['name']);
```

I extracted this last part from: [Codeigniter $this->db->get(), how do I return values for a specific row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541291/codeigniter-this-db-get-how-do-i-return-values-for-a-specific-row#8541303) that you could check too.

If you don't know a lof of CI, the best you can do is do a simple tutorial to understand how the data + ActiveRecord works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: since I'm using the info in a model I'm not sure how to actually view the var_dump. I'm super new to CI so I still have a ton to learn.

Comment: Check for my update, you should have access to you data with that.

Comment: Yup so the ['name'] part of $data[0]['name'] is what I was missing. I thought because it was only grabbing the names it wouldn't need the 'name' attribute to access it.