# How to get a single element in sql query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get user ip address based on users id. I don't get why it doesn't work.

In the controller:

```
function block_user($name,$user_id)
{
    $ip = $this->m_db->get_ips($user_id);
     $data = array(
    'username' => $name ,
    'ip' => $ip ,
    );
$this->db->insert('blacklist', $data);

$this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
$this->db->delete('comments');
$this->index();
}
```

In the model:

```
function get_ips($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('ip');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeIgniter - return only one row?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4280235/3506027)

What you should do is return a row

```
function get_ips($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('ip');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $ret = $query->row();
    return $ret->ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make all transaction database in your model, then you need to use

```
$this->db->get();
```

The correct way is:
controller.php

```
function block_user($name,$user_id){
    $re = $this->m_db->get_ips($user_id, $name);

    echo $re;
}
```

model.php

```
function insert_data($ip, $name){
    $data = array(
                  'username' => $name ,
                  'ip'       => $ip ,
                  );

    $this->db->insert('blacklist', $data);

    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $this->db->delete('comments');

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}

function get_ips($user_id, $name){
    $this->db->select('ip');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->row();

    $resp = $this->insert_data($query, $name);

    return $resp;
}
```